# Is it possible to make API calls from MAMP PRO

Tags: apache, api, rest, localhost, mamp-pro

I have a localhost setup using MAMP PRO and XIP.IO for sharing on my local network.

I'm also trying to test API requests from with the same application but I keep getting the following error in the log file even though I am using the correct API credentials which work on a remote server.

```
2015-12-20T12:52:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-type: text/html
Date: Sun, 20 Dec 2015 12:52:52 GMT
Server: nginx
Www-authenticate: Basic realm="very closed site"
Content-length: 188
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

If this is indeed due to being on a localhost is there a way to recieve API callbacks using MAMP PRO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the third party API to be able to send you a post back, your local website/app must be accessible when entering your public IP.

So if I understand your problem you just have to configure your router (or internet provider box) and open a port that you redirect to your local MAMP Pro. You can find a lot of tutorial for "Access MAMP Pro remotely"

**WARNING : Do this for tests and then close the port you openned not to leave a security breach**